# XMLElement only contains first child node

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service that getting sent XML files where the nodes can vary although the root elements are always the same. Some files may look like this:

```
<MyXML xmlns="something">
  <xmlDoc>
    <element1>Value</element1>
    <element2>Value</element2>
  </xmlDoc>
</MyXML>
```

While others look like this

```
<MyXML xmlns="something">
  <xmlDoc>
    <otherelement1>Value</otherelement1>
    <child1>
       <element3>Value</element3>
       <element2>Value</element2>
     </child1>
  </xmlDoc>
</MyXML>
```

Because I have no way of knowing how these will look, what I wanted to do is just grab the whole  element and then parse through it but right now I can only get the first child element (element1). My service interface looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "auth")]
    ResponseData Auth(MyXML rData);
}
```

and my datacontract looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "something")]
public class MyXML
{
    [DataMember]
    public XmlElement xmlDoc { get; set; }
}
```

But in my service I am only ever getting the first element from the XML -- ie

```
<element1>Value</element1>
```

So my question is, will this work? What do I need to change? I tried the data contract as a List instead

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "something")]
public class MyXML
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<XmlElement> xmlDoc { get; set; }
}
```

but that just returned an empty list. I am very new to WCF so let me know if any other details are needed.

Comment: How you are returning the Xml document at MyXML class?

Comment: @ Mino -- The reponse format being XML is really just a placeholder for now -- when I said 'returns' the first child node I really just meant that when I step through the code I can see that the XmlElement xmlDoc only contains the first child node. Probably a bad choice of words so I updated the title

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out this was REALLY easy to workaround -- I`m actually writing the XML from an android app so I have the luxury of changing the structure. I simply added an inner node so my XML went from this

```
<MyXML xmlns="something">
<xmlDoc>
 <otherelement1>Value</otherelement1>
   <child1>
     <element3>Value</element3>
     <element2>Value</element2>
   </child1>
 </xmlDoc>
```

to this:

```
<MyXML xmlns="something">
<xmlDoc>
 <xmlDocInner>
  <otherelement1>Value</otherelement1>
    <child1>
      <element3>Value</element3>
      <element2>Value</element2>
    </child1>
  </xmlDocInner>
 </xmlDoc>
```

So now I get everything inside the xmlDocInner node when I get the xmlDoc element. It still begs the question of how one would get the entire element if there is no inner node as a buffer but I am ok with this as is.

Comment: Did you try to return XDocument ?

Comment: Do you mean having a data member of type XDocument for xmlDocInner (according to the structure in this answer)? I tried just now but its value is null

Answer (score 0):

To access the raw XML, [use the `Message` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675(v=vs.110).aspx), not a `DataContract`.  If you want a POCO to help you along, you are probably stuck with `XmlSerializer`.

```
static class SchemaConstants
{
    public const string Namespace = "something";
}

[XmlType(Namespace = SchemaConstants.Namespace)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = SchemaConstants.Namespace)]
public class xmlDoc 
{
    // case 1
    public string element1;
    public string element2;

    // case 2
    public string otherelement1;
    public child1 child1;
}

[XmlType(Namespace = SchemaConstants.Namespace)]
public class child1
{
    public string element3;
    public string element2;
}
```

Any member not present will be deserialized as null.  You will have to [mark your contract or service implementation with the `[XmlSerializerFormat]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx).

Results for your first example:

[image: picture of visual studio watch window showing element1 and 2 with values, and all others null]

Results for your second example:

[image: picture of visual studio watch window showing element1 and 2 null, and all others with a value]

You can also use a type which implements the `IXmlSerializer` interface and handle the deserialization yourself.

Comment: Hmmm...could you explain why the answer below wouldn`t be a good solution? The reason I ask is that the XML node names (and even nesting levels) could change an arbitrary amount of times, so I would prefer to not have to keep track of every single possible node name. Besides, by grabbing the entire XML element I can just iterate through all the child nodes where I can get all the XML data. Are there any performance reasons why I wouldn`t just want to use the whole XML element?

Comment: Because you are double wrapping your data.  As I mentioned in the answer, you can access the raw XML by accepting `Message` rather than a typed construct - you don't need to use `xmlDocInner` to achieve the same.  Note, however, that it is a best practice to use a schema to ensure the XML is valid and allow for code generation on the client side while eliminating the need to manually create the XML.  For Java, see http://tinyurl.com/lvntm2a or http://tinyurl.com/ko7x8vg.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation and effort but validating the xml here doesn`t make sense because I also write the code which generates the XML document in the first place; so by validating the XML I would just be keeping track of the same thing twice. The XML generation is simply going through generic lists and using the java XmlSerializer class to construct the XML and I am not sure how that is ever avoidable here. I will take your suggestions into consideration if I find myself on a project where I don`t have complete control over both ends however.

Comment: You can never have too much validation regardless of whether it is provided by Unit Tests or Schemas, or for yourself or others, a single typo can cause untold pain which may not be noticed in manual testing.  If you are referring to JAXB, you can generate the XSD with `JAXBContext.generateSchema()`, and generate your C# from the XSD with `xsd.exe`.  See http://tinyurl.com/np5ndwh to generate the XSD, and http://tinyurl.com/kx7xkxr to generate the C#.

Comment: Besides, it is _easier_ in most modern toolkits to do it "right".  You have to do less, and get strongly typed contracts between server and client.  If you clue us in to the java client API you are using or your use case, I can give a more concrete example.

Comment: Right on. So, on the java side I am manipulating the Bluetooth Controller on an android phone to get device information from a remotely paired device. This is entirely based on the Bluetooth spec which of course changes frequently so I have a 3 helper classes -- a "feature" which contains a String (ID) and a ArrayList<String>. The ID could be "Role" and the ArrayList of features would be simply "Handsfree Audio Gateway." Or, the ID could be "Supported Features" in which case the ArrayList would be "3-way Calling", "Wide-Band Speech", and "Codec Negotiation".

Comment: Next, I have an ArrayList<Feature>. This encompasses every piece of information about any one specific Bluetooth Profile. Finally, I have a class which is an ArrayList<FeatureArrayList> which essentially contains all Bluetooth Profile information about the remote device. Now to build the XML I use org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer and have an XmlSerializer object. I simply iterate in a for loop through my ArrayList<FeatureArrayList> and its children and build the XML. It is literally only 10 lines of code and executes pretty much instantaneously.

Comment: Then on the WCF side I read the XML and update a MSSQL database. Right now I am really keeping track of XML node names in two places -- in the Bluetooth decoders on the Android side and in the database on the other side, since I named my database columns with the same names as I give the Feature IDs on the other side